# Word for to learn more, expand knowledge, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word in English the fits the meaning of:

To learn more about a subject through reading, discussing, etc.

Here's some context: this is an abstract of the full article. For those who wish to ______, the full article can be found at WWW.XXX.COM.

Thanks!

Comment: There are lots of words for learn. To *learn more* requires two words; in the context of your example, *learn more* is perfect. Other constructions become awkward: educate themselves further, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a single word that fits the OP's request, the phrase "to learn more" is the easiest and most idiomatic solution but there are other viable alternatives.

> 1. For those who wish to **delve deeper**, the full article can be found at WWW.XXX.Com.

To *delve deeper into something* implies that the article under discussion is fairly vast. To *delve* means to to examine something more closely, to physically search for something.

Otherwise, if the op is interested in creating a more succinct phrasing then may I suggest the following

> 2. **Further details** of the full article can be found at WWW.XXX.Com.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "for those who wish to learn more"
or "for further reading".

The term "self-enrichment" comes to mind, but it sounds awkward in the context you've supplied.

chris

Comment: Hi Chris- thanks for your suggestions- but I'm curious if there is a one-word answer. I agree that "self-enrichment" sounds awkward...

Comment: Maybe you could just say "for more, the full article can be found at blah.bla."     One could argue that it's lacking in specificity. but that shortcoming is redeemed a bit by context, especially as (i'm guessing) it will be used over and over in a series of entries.

Answer (score 0):

As a single word [read](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Read) may fit: (from TFD)

> - To examine and grasp the meaning of (written or printed characters, words, or sentences).

Comment: Hi Josh - I don't think I could use the word "study" here. Could you replace the blank in the sentence above with study? I don't think it works...